# Unable to change camera view when using Gaze Cursor Example

Tags: aframe

I used the example code from the [Github](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/cursor.md) and plugged it into a boilerplate page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello, World! • A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, World! • A-Frame">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aframe/0.7.0/aframe-master.js"></script>
    <script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
      init: function () {
        var lastIndex = -1;
        var COLORS = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
        this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
          lastIndex = (lastIndex + 1) % COLORS.length;
          this.setAttribute('material', 'color', COLORS[lastIndex]);
          console.log('I was clicked at: ', evt.detail.intersection.point);
        });
      }
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-entity camera>
        <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500"
                  position="0 0 -1"
                  geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03"
                  material="color: black; shader: flat">
        </a-entity>
      </a-entity>

      <a-entity id="box" cursor-listener geometry="primitive: box" material="color: blue" position="0, 0, -4"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this code snippet, I am using the cdn for aframe 0.7.0 but have also attempted 0.7.1 and master.

The cursor appears to "click" the cube once, changing its color. The view is unable to be moved in both desktop and VR mode. For example, in VR mode, when moving my head, the rectangle stays in the direct center of view.

Here is a live [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YeopJb?editors=1000#0).

How do I fix the code to allow me to be able to move the camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to add the look-controls component to your camera:

`<a-entity camera look-controls>`